# Localhost, subdomain, using XAMPP

Tags: php, windows-7, xampp

I am a web developer and frequently want to view different projects on my local machine. Currently my localhost is set to "C:/xampp/htdocs/". I would like to create a "company.localhost" that points to "C:/xampp/htdocs/company/".

I have edited c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts to include the line

```
127.0.0.1 company.localhost
```

I have edited c:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf to include

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName company.localhost
    ServerAlias company.localhost
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/company/"
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm index.shtml
</VirtualHost>
```

When I navigate to http://company.localhost in my browser (using Chrome), it shows me the localhost index page. I have started and restarted my Apache server. How do I get to company.localhost/index.php in my browser?

I am on Windows 7.

EDIT: Now both http://localhost and http://company.localhost are pointing to the index page for company.localhost. How do I get my normal localhost index back and still keep correct index page for company.localhost?

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe it helps, on windows use \ and not /

Comment: I was copying the examples in the vhosts file, but I'll give it a shot. EDIT: now it tells me the webpage is unavailable.

Comment: Using the backslashes instead of forward slashes caused an error that made Apache stop suddenly.

Comment: Soz, i'm not a guru of apache. But thats strange, I'm using windows and xampp and use that slash.
Let's wait someone come and help you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When creating more than one virtual host on the same port, you must specify each host name. Otherwise you only have one site bound to port 80, and all localhost calls will direct to the folder you specified.

Here is the missing code, add just before or after similar code in c:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias localhost
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/"
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm index.shtml
</VirtualHost>
```